# Textmate editing 2 words at same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textmate, text-editor

I am not 100% sure if this is the right place to be posting this question, but I could not think of anywhere else.

I having been using textmate for around 6 months to write Ruby on Rails applications.

The snippets and stuff are nice.  I am wondering if it is possible to edit to words at the same time.  I am using the `mcol` snippet which generates a `add_column` and `remove_column` in a database migration.

When the code is generated it highlights the `table_name` and changes both occurences of the word `table_name` when you start typing.

Hoping that this can be done to any word that you select.

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the whole idea of TextMate is to have an editable editor(!), if you look at the HTML bundle, the shortcut ctrl-shift-w invokes this:

```
<${1:p}>$TM_SELECTED_TEXT</${1/\s.*//}>
```

So, to add a custom shortcut to wrap a selection in a pair of editable text strings (which is what you want, I think?), go to `Bundles > Show Bundle Editor` then choose `New Snippet` from the add `+` button (bottom left) and use (e.g.):

```
${1:editme}$TM_SELECTED_TEXT${1/\s.*//}
```

where 'editme' is the default 'doubly-editable' value. If you add a new snippet shortcut in the 'Key Equivalent' field (I used ctrl-shift-alt-W) you can then wrap any selection in an editable pair of words. Depending on what you need, the same syntax might be expanded to match your requirements?

Note: once the shortcut is allocated, you can't edit a snippet in place - you need to start again (I think - couldn't find a way around that).